# javascript touch screen solution

Tags: javascript, touchscreen

What are the best/recommended javascript libraries/solutions for touch screens? I'm asking this question because technology is changing fast and what I could find about this topic is few years old and may be deprecated. And also I'm not interested in legacy browsers support.

Comment: modern browsers support basic touch interactions, you don't need any additional library to handle them. for complex touch interactions like multitouch you have to choose the library that matches what you need.

Comment: This is a very wide question to answer but I agree with @softwarenewbie7331 everything you need is here at your finger tips (no pun intended) you just need to play around and choose what you feel works best for you and your project